# Grails : Passing property using meta tag

Tags: grails

Is there any possible ways to pass parameter using `meta` tag, for example 
`<meta name="layout" content="bootstrap" params="[params:${name}]"/>` which is not working.

Comment: The meta tag is an actual HTML tag, not a Grails _tag_, so the params attribute is not used to pass on data. Which data do you want to use in the layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to pass on a simple parameter to your Grails layout is to define a parameter in the view you are rendering:

```
<parameter name="name" value="${name}" />
```

And than access the value of that parameter in the layout using the Grails [pageProperty](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Tags/pageProperty.html) tag:

```
<body class="${pageProperty(name: 'body.class')} >
```